# Laravel signup method

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, authorization

am trying to do simple function, signup function. Am new in laravel so really does not know why this is not working...
Am getting 419 Page Expired in insomnia.

So this is my method code:

```
    public function signup(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->validate([
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|min:5|confirmed',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required',
        ];
        
        $registeredUser = User::create($data);

        return response()->json($registeredUser);
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::prefix('api/v1')->group(function () {

    Route::group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function () {

        /** signup */
        Route::post('/signup', 'AuthController@signup');
    });
});
```

So whats wrong with this code? why am getting 419?

Comment: 419 error code means that you are not sending the csrf token share your blade code

Comment: You probably did not enter csrt_token in the form. Are you sure about the presence of csrf_token in the form?

Comment: Hello guys, thanks for your responses :). I don't want to use a blade, I want to create API requests and then with insomnia/postman send requests. So ai think am doing something wrong here ye?  : )

Comment: One of the ways is to set the value `'api/v1/*'` in the middleware `VerifyCsrfToken` and `$except` property.

Comment: Really don't know how to do it... Is there any tutorial on how to do laravel API requests?, Am asking because I didn't find any... How to do simple request like this, like registration...

Comment: If these routes are in `api.php`, then it should automatically bypass the VerifyCsrfToken middleware. If they are not in api.php, then move them there. You won't need the `api` in your prefix there

Comment: Thanks a lot, ye that was the issue, i moved routes in api.php, but i think now i have problem with returning json. now i get 200 in insomnia but its loads page, i need to get json, so i thins maybe there is problem with return response json?

Comment: Your controller is returning a json, so you should be getting a json. Double-check the route with `php artisan route:list` and make sure there isn't a double api shown, and that it matches the routes you're using with your script.

Comment: I checked the list, and in the list, everything is all right POST - api/signup - AuthController@signup
Maybe it's needed in the header or something?